# Dimension of irreducible module divides the dimension of the algebra?

Tags: finite-groups, modules, representation-theory

**Fact:** $\chi(1)$ divides order of $|G|$ where $\chi$ is an irreducible character of $G$.

Above fact is equivalent to say that if $V$ is an irreducible $A=\mathbb C [G]$ module then $\dim(V)$ divides $\dim(A)$.

I wonder that whether this fact can be proven by modules.(without using character theory)

I also wonder that whether it is true for general case;

If $A$ is an algebra over $\mathbb C$ and $V$ is an irreducible $A$ module then $\dim(V)\mid\dim(A)$ ?

Comment: For the second question, the answer is "no" in general. For example, consider $A = M_{1}(\mathbb{C}) \oplus M_{p}(\mathbb{C})$ where $p$ is a prime. $A$ has dimension $p^{2}+1$ and $A$ has an irreducible module of dimension $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would doubt there is a general fact. First of all because of Jim's counterexample. Secondly, because it fails in positive characteristic (take $\operatorname{SL}(2,p)$ for $p$ odd, see, e.g. [Curtis-Reiner, (17.17)]).

It is probably worth pointing out that in the special case that $A$ is a semisimple Hopf algebra over a field of characteristic zero, this is called Kaplansky's sixth conjecture. There is a [mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/108404/15887) on that, pointing you to several nice survey articles. I haven't looked at the papers containing partial results. It might be that some of them contain more "character-free" approaches.

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ and $B$ are both algebras and $V$ is an irreducible $A$-module, then $V$ is also an irreducible $A \oplus B$ module (where $B$ acts trivially).  As the dimension of $A \oplus B$ is $\dim A + \dim B$ and $B$ is essentially arbitrary the answer is no, $\dim(V)$ needn't divide the dimension of the algebra.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: It means that every element of $B$ acts as $0$ on $V$.  The identity of $B$ **does not** need to act on $V$ as the identity, because it is not the identity of $A \oplus B$.  You are right that $B$ *could* act on $V$, if this were a different action, but you are wrong that $B$ *must* act on $V$.  Remember that I'm defining the action here.

Comment: Put another way, projection $A \oplus B \to A$ is an *algebra* morphism and I'm composing it with the representation $A \to \mathrm{End}(V)$.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry about the brain fart, Jim.

Comment: @jim: What about firt question, do you have an any idea ?

Comment: Nope, I have no clue.